# Как изменить директорию сохранения файла методами aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

Подскажите, как изменить директорию сохранения файла, который юзер отсылает боту.

На текущий момент кусок кода, который занимается сохранением выглядит вот так

```
@dp.message_handler(state = States.S_FILE, content_types=['document'])
async def get_file(message, state: FSMContext):
    chat_id = message.chat.id

    file_id = message.document.file_id
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id)
    file_path = file.file_path
    name = message.document.file_name
    await bot.download_file(file_path, name)
```

Сами файл прилетают в корневой каталог, пытался менять аргументы, добавлять пути, но опытным путем выяснил, что ни одна из переменных на деле не хранит пути локальной машины

Comment: `file.file_path` вероятно хранит путь файла с компьютера отправителя, а вы его используете как путь для сохранения файла на сервере. Никто не мешает использовать другой путь :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await bot.download_file(file_path, 'documents/'+name)
```

Добавление такой штуки помогло. Зачем-то path добавлял с другой стороны...